# HTML terminology question:TBODY vs P

Tags: html, terminology

A TBODY tag can normally hold a number of TR tags.

P tag usually holds just textual data.

Is there any special terminology in HTML to differentiate this type of behavior of TBODY? Can I say TBODY is a 'container' type of TAG as opposed to a P tag?

Comment: As this is a terminology question, "element" is more appropriate than "tag". Tags refer to the markup syntax. Elements refer to the HTML elements themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TBODY, THEAD, and TFOOT elements are specifically described as "row groups": http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY

Similarly, DIVs are described as "grouping" elements.

P elements are known as "text" elements.